# dialog on hover check if visible on screen

Tags: jquery, css, dialog, hover, fullcalendar

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    //console.log($(this).find('.fc-content').text());
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(calEvent));
    //var data = JSON.stringify(calEvent);
    //console.log(JSON.parse(data)['start']);
    //console.log(JSON.parse(data)['end']);
    var exResult = dataFromTimestamp(calEvent.start * 1000)
        //console.log(exResult.fullDate+' '+exResult.fullTime);
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="padding:3px;width:250px;height:150px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">Description:<br>' + calEvent.description + '<hr>Other Information:<br>' + calEvent.otherinformation + '</div>'; //'<hr>Start Time:' + JSON.parse(data)['start'] + '<hr>End Time:' + JSON.parse(data)['end'] +
    $("body").append(tooltip);
    $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
        $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        //                var x = $(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth();
        //                var y = $(this).position().top - $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        //                $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
        //                    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY -150);
        $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
        //console.log(View($('.tooltipevent')));
        console.log(elementInViewport($('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10)))
    });
}
```

This is my hover on event. When i hover on event i show a tooptip that is always next to the mouse pointer. My problem is when the event is at the bottom of screen when you hover the event the tooltip is not visible because it is too low on the screen. I tried many function as ff:

```
function View(elem) {
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    //    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    //    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).position().top
    var elemBottom = $(elem).outerHeight(true)
        //For elemTop I used $(elem).position().top and for elemBottom I used elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight(true)


    //    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    return (((elemTop >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)) || ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom)));
}

function elementInViewport(el) {
    var top = el.offsetTop;
    var left = el.offsetLeft;
    var width = el.offsetWidth;
    var height = el.offsetHeight;

    while (el.offsetParent) {
        el = el.offsetParent;
        top += el.offsetTop;
        left += el.offsetLeft;
    }

    return (
        top >= window.pageYOffset &&
        left >= window.pageXOffset &&
        (top + height) <= (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
        (left + width) <= (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth)
    );
}
```

But both are not working as expected.when i do

```
console.log(View($('.tooltipevent')));
console.log(elementInViewport($('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10)))
```

First one always return `true` even if the tooltip is visible or not while the second one always return `false` even if the tooltip is visible or not

What i want is when part of the tootip is not visible or over the screen

use

```
$('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY - 150);
$('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
```

So that the tooltip will appear on top of the mouse pointer else

```
$('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
$('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.pageY + 150 > $(window).height()) {
    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY - 150);
} else {
    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
}
```

Use `e.pageY + 150 > $(window).height()` to check if the dialog will be over the screen.

- e.pageY -> Position of the event.
- 150 -> height of tooltip
- $(window).height() -> window height